# Can we install player/stage and Ros in a same system?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any problem in installing player/stage to a computer with ROS? We are using two version of ROS.

Hydro in Ubuntu 12.04(32bit and 64bit) and Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04(32 bit)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175029/can-we-install-player/stage-and-ros-in-a-same-system?/) by [robospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/18911/robospace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No problem. I am using stage with Hydro and Indigo as well. Not sure what the exact differences are, but I am using the "ros version" of stage (http://wiki.ros.org/stage) and the ros-stage interface (http://wiki.ros.org/stage_ros).

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2014-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/18911/robospace/) on 2014-06-26**:
Are you using player in the same computer with ROS?

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-06-26**:
I am not using player